# htaccess url alias / clean urls - php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hello I've bee trying for 1 week now to fix some urls on my custom built site but I can't accomplish what I want 100%. So here is my question:

I have a php landing page that manages events the default url structure is this:

```
foreach($resultSet as $key => $event)
{
    echo '<a href="/event.php?eid='.$event['eid'].'&cat='.$event['categroy'].'&title='.urlencode($event['title']).'">content</a>';
}
```

As you can see the url format is like this

`/event.php?eid=145&cat=metal&title=Great+gig`

What I would like it to be through htaccess is something like this

`domain.com/event/metal/Great gig`

I've been reading htaccess guides but I cant make it work with more tahn 1 params on the url please advise, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change your php code so that it generates URLs that look like `domain.com/event/metal/Great gig`:

   ```
   echo '<a href="/event/'.$event['eid'].'/'.$event['categroy'].'/'.urlencode($event['title']).'">content</a>';
   ```

   (Note that the `'category'` is mispelled in your example)
2. Add these rules in the htaccess file in your **document root**, preferably above any rules you may have already there:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^/?event/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)$ /event.php?eid=$1&cat=$2&title=$3 [L,QSA]
   ```

Additionally, if you have links that are out of your control that still have the query string, you can add these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /event\.php\?eid=([^&]+)&cat=([^&]+)&title=([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /event/%2/%3/%4? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! May I ask 1 more thing would it be possible in order to hide the eid from the url alias to create only 1 get variable that will pass the whole thing like 
?var=category/title/eid/ and then somehow in htaccess to exclude the eid part ?

Comment: @PanagiotisGeorgeRaditsas If you exclude the eid from the URI, then it will never get passed to the `event.php` script. If you don't need the eid, then just remove the match for it, (the first `([^/]+)/` and remove the target `eid=$1&` and renumber the backreferences to start at **1**)

Comment: The issue i'm facing is that i have multiple event with the same title because 1 event can repeat weekly and so on... but each event has a unique event id (eid) which i have to use in order to get the event i want.Any ideas how to accomplish this ?

Comment: @PanagiotisGeorgeRaditsas Then you **have** to include the eid in the nice looking URLs. Otherwise, you'd lose them permanently.